# Call non-global function from string variable

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

As expected, this code:

```
s = "bar"
bar = function() print(s) end
_G[s]()
```

outputs:

> bar

but either this:

```
s = "bar"
foo = {
    bar = function() print(s) end,
    _G["foo." .. s]()
}
```

or this:

```
s = "bar"
foo = {
    bar = function() print(s) end
}
_G["foo." .. s]()
```

outputs:

> attempt to call field '?' (a nil value)
>   stack traceback:
>     test.lua:4: in main chunk
>     [C]: ?

How to call non-global function from string variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "bar"
foo = {
    bar = function() print(s) end
}
_G["foo." .. s]()
```

This last method doesn't work because there is no such table `"foo.bar"`, but rather the field `"bar"` in the table `foo`. So you can call it like this:

```
_G.foo[s]()
```

or simply:

```
foo[s]()
```